# Error checking in action creators

Tags: javascript, redux

I was wondering if error checking is allowed in action creators. And if it is, should we return undefined from the action creator?

For instance I have this

```
        function setFps(value) {
            // value is int 1-60
            if (value >= 1 && value <= 60)
                return {
                    type: SET_FPS,
                    value
                };
            } else {
                return undefined; // proper?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't check for invalid values before calling the action creator you have two options:

1. You may send an **error** action, to which the reducer may act accordingly.
2. You may throw an `Error` and catch it in the function that invokes the action

**Edit:**

This is a good idea if

- the error value is directly created by the user
- there should be a state change or side effect as a result of the error

It is **not** a good idea if

- the error only exists due to programmatic errors before (think HTTP 50x responses)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So it is a good idea to check in the action creator? Sending an error action would require middleware like redux-thunk no?

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel. I don't understand the final bullet error type (50x errors) may you please explain that a bit more if you have some free time in the future

Comment: By that I mean internal errors, e.g. your api send the wrong response or the values returned by another function don't seem to be right

Comment: No problem :) Hope it helped.

Comment: Oh one more thing Daniel please. In the action creator, if it's an invalid value, should I return `undefined`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114611/discussion-between-daniel-schmidt-and-noitidart).